# How to write Strapi filtering queries to get the amount in given category

Tags: strapi

Is it possible to write an url like this in Strapi? Where I want to get the amount of articles with a given category.

```
const url = `/articles?category=${params}/count`
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible, you where close.

`{{host}}/articles/count?category=1`
or
`{{host}}/articles/count?category.name=basedOnAField`